# Java Networking - Limit login attempts not looping through

Tags: java, if-statement, networking, while-loop, server

I'm making a short program where the user will enter the username and password only the server knows. They have 4 tries to get it right, and if they do not enter the correct info they will be kicked off the server.

If the user enters the incorrect login the first time, it allows them to enter the username and password again and tells them they have 3 tries. But after this, it gets stuck and does not loop again. How can I fix this?

The code:

```
int tries = 4;
        while (tries>=0) {
            out.println(login);

            //login
            String username = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

            String password = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);

            if (username.equals("hello123") && password.equals("mypass")) {
                out.println("Correct login!");
                System.out.println ("Client's IP Address: " + localaddr.getHostAddress());
            }

            else if (!username.equals("hello123")||!password.equals("mypass")) { //if wrong login - give 3 more tries

                tries--;
                System.out.println("Number of tries left: " + tries);
                out.println("Try again, enter username and password. Login attempts left - " + tries);

                //login
                username = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

                password = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);
            }
        }
        if (tries==0){
            out.println("Wrong login - server closing");
            out.close();
            skt.close();
            srvr.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
int tries = 4;
        while (tries>=0) {
            out.println(login);

            //login
            String username = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

            String password = in.readLine();
            System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);

            if (username.equals("hello123") && password.equals("mypass")) {
                out.println("Correct login!");
                System.out.println ("Client's IP Address: " + localaddr.getHostAddress());
            }

            else if (!username.equals("hello123")||!password.equals("mypass")) { //if wrong login - give 3 more tries

                tries--;
                System.out.println("Number of tries left: " + tries);
                out.println("Try again, enter username and password. Login attempts left - " + tries);
            }
        }
        if (tries==0){
            out.println("Wrong login - server closing");
            out.close();
            skt.close();
            srvr.close();
        }
```

Comment: I think the code //login
                username = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

                password = in.readLine();
                System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);   inside the else if block is not needed.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! But when they get the username and password correct after the 1st try, it still asks them to enter the login info again, which it shouldn't.

Comment: Inside if block, give a break; ie, if (username.equals("hello123") && password.equals("mypass")) {
                out.println("Correct login!");
                System.out.println ("Client's IP Address: " + localaddr.getHostAddress());  break;
            } .   Hope it solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to keep the while loop running, reset the tries to 4 once you reached 0th try. For example.

```
    while(true){
           //rest of the code
            if (tries==0){
                out.println("Wrong login - server closing");
                out.close();
                skt.close();
                srvr.close();
                tries = 4;
            }
}
```

You should use try/catch/finally or try with resources in order to do a graceful exit.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the readLine() in your if statement, and reset tries=4 when the username and password is correct or tries == 0.Finally put the tries==0 if statement into while loop.

```
  int tries = 4;
    while (tries>=0) {
        out.println(login);
        //login
        String username = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client's username: " + username);

        String password = in.readLine();
        System.out.println("Client's password: " + password);

        if (username.equals("hello123") && password.equals("mypass")) {
            out.println("Correct login!");
            System.out.println ("Client's IP Address: " + localaddr.getHostAddress());
            tries = 4;
        }

        else if (!username.equals("hello123")||!password.equals("mypass")) { //if wrong login - give 3 more tries

            tries--;
            System.out.println("Number of tries left: " + tries);
            out.println("Try again, enter username and password. Login attempts left - " + tries);
        }
       if (tries==0){
          out.println("Wrong login - server closing");
          tries = 4;
       }
    }
```